# Struggling to understand the behavior of the window<-.ts function in R

Tags: r, time-series

Consider the following code that creates two `ts` time-series *foo* & *bar*:

```
x = 1:22
foo = ts(x, start = 1.5, end = 106.5, frequency = 0.2)
bar = ts(x, start = 2.5, end = 107.5, frequency = 0.2)
```

The *foo* and *bar* objects are identical except for the start and end values: for *bar* they are both larger by 1. Neither start/end values are exactly multiples of the frequency, but that shouldn't pose a problem.
Indeed, for both *foo* and *bar*, a window of an arbitrary size can be successfully extracted:

```
stats::window(foo, start = 20, end = 30)  # works fine
stats::window(bar, start = 20, end = 30)  # works fine too
```

But if I try to assign values to these windows, only *foo* works:

```
window(foo, start = 20, end = 30) <- NA  # works fine
window(bar, start = 20, end = 30) <- NA  # ERROR!!!
```

> Error in attr(y, "tsp") <- c(ystart, yend, xfreq) :
>      invalid time series parameters specified

the internal working of `window<-.ts` basically calls the stats::window function, so it should work just as well as calling the `window()` function explicitly.

---

My understanding is that in the *ts* definition, 'start' and 'end' are just in arbitrary units, eg: seconds. So `ts(x, start = 1.5, end = 106.5, frequency = 0.2)` may mean: a series that starts at second 1.5 and ends at second 106.5, where each number represents 5 seconds (1/frequency).
The `stat::window` function then, just selects the values that are within its start-end boundaries, eg: from 20 to 30 seconds. And indeed the `time()` for both windows is the same and seems to confirm this:

```
time(window(foo, start = 20, end = 30))
[1] 21.5 26.5
time(window(bar, start = 20, end = 30))
[1] 22.5 27.5
```

The fact that one series starts at 1.5s and the other at 2.5s has absolutely no impact on the windowing procedure. Yet when assigning values to it, my logic breaks.

Things get even wilder by removing one cycle from *bar*:

```
qux = ts(1:21, start = 2.5, end = 102.5, frequency = 0.2)
window(qux, start = 20, end = 30) <- NA  #ERROR!!
```

> Error in `window<-.ts`(`*tmp*`, start = 20, end = 30, value = NA) : 
>    times to be replaced do not match

A different error! I think I am failing to understand some fundamental concept.
**So what am I missing here?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you say `window<-.ts()` uses `window()` internally to create the new object. It's done via `eval.parent()`, where `window()` is called with `extend=TRUE`, and this is when the error occurs. As such we can simplify our analysis by instead considering the following pair

```
window(foo, start=20, end=30, extend=TRUE)  # works fine
# Time Series:
# Start = 20 
# End = 25 
# Frequency = 0.2 
# [1] 5 6

window(bar, start=20, end=30, extend=TRUE)  # error
# Error in attr(y, "tsp") <- c(ystart, yend, xfreq) : 
#   invalid time series parameters specified
```

the `attr(y, "tsp") <- c(ystart, yend, xfreq)` mentioned in the error message happens at the very end of `stats:::window.default`. The actual values used are

```
# for foo
y <- 5:6
attr(y, "tsp") <- c(20, 25, 0.2)

# for bar
y <- 5:6
attr(y, "tsp") <- c(20, 30, 0.2)
```

The 25/30 discrepancy is due to rounding earlier in the code, but why does one work, while the other doesn't? It's the frequency. A frequency of less than one seems a bit odd to me. See, if you set the frequency to 12, f.ex, you have 12 samples per period or cycle. Maybe once a month, or maybe every second hour, but every 12th sample should have something in common. If you set frequency to 1, you effectively have no period, you sample once a year and know of no significant cycles longer that are in multiple of years. What would a frequency of less than 1 mean? I guess a frequency of say 0.5 could mean that sampling is done every second year, and 0.2 then every fifth year? Maybe that's informative, I don't know.

But why the error? While both 25-20 and 30-20 divides by 5 just fine, the latter one is one element short. Use `y <- 5:7` instead and it works just fine.
Why does it work for `foo` but not `bar`? Because rounding.
But why though? Probably because no-one tested the function using time series with frequency of less than one.

---

A possible fix could be to use `zoo` class time series, instead of standard `ts`. It works well in this case, but I haven't done any other tests.

```
library(zoo)

foo.z <- as.zoo(foo)
bar.z <- as.zoo(bar)

window(foo.z, start = 20, end = 30) <- NA  # works fine
window(bar.z, start = 20, end = 30) <- NA  # also works fine
```

Comment: That's a good answer, thanks. I have many physiological series, where it makes sense that the frequency is expressed in samples per seconds, i.e. Hertz. Most of my data has about 10 or 100 samples per seconds, but then, slower signals are sampled only once every 5 or 30 seconds. So frequencies lower than one make totally sense, just as 0.5Hz makes sense in signal processing. Apparently there's no solution though, if not rewriting a custom ts class, or changing one "round()" to "floor()" in the window function, which may lead to other unwanted consequences somewhere else.... :-(

Comment: @Johann: It seems like a solution could be to use `zoo`.

Comment: Another workaround would be to change the time scale. The second in Hz isn't any more special than the minute in RPM. Instead of 0.5/sec you could have 30/min.

Comment: Also possibly a relevant discussion on CV: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/120806/frequency-value-for-seconds-minutes-intervals-data-in-r

Comment: Changing the time-scale to minutes would be quite unnatural for the package users, being base60 whereas most physiological signals are described with base10 frequencies (e.g. 100 samples per second would become 6000  samples per minute).

Comment: Migrating to zoo may actually be most painless solution, thanks again!